# ROS Answers SE migration: duckietown

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I built myself a duckiebot as described in http://duckietown.mit.edu - and after a lot of work it works nicely. (well kind of)

Of course I have a lot of questions, but the main code repository at https://github.com/duckietown seems not really active. They are probably working for the second version of the robot, which I can understand, sometimes replying basic email is very distracting while you are working on robotic hardware.

So my question is this "Can we have a duckietown section on answers.ros.org?" - I replicated results and fixed some minor stuff due to using kinetic instead of indigo. I still have a lot of questions, and I understand there are others who also replicated results and have questions too.

Also the documentation for the duckietown project does not really cover all the code. For example there are localization.launch and localization_frontend.launch files, and when launched with the help of markers attached to the corner of the robot ground, will show where the robot is on rviz. There are many more demos like these.

Any ideas/recomendations/help greatly appreciated.

C.A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263071/duckietown/) by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2017-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the suggestion.

We decided to encourage people to use answers.ros.org with tag "`duckietown`" when they have questions.

---

Originally posted by [Andrea Censi](https://answers.ros.org/users/786/andrea-censi/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1